# Extract web data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract several information from the following structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spmfT.png)

I have used the following code:

```
text = soup.find_all('ul', class_='lista-tabelara')
for my_text in text:
    x = my_text.li.text
    print(x)
```

The result will get me:
Nr. camere:5
Suprafaţă teren:400 mp

My intention is to extract a list of values as following:
('5', ... '1', '400 mp', ....) 
There are more 'li' tag there and exclude the '::marker' text

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use following **css** selector `select`

```
text = soup.find_all('ul', class_='lista-tabelara')
for my_text in text:
    x =[item.text for item in my_text.select('li>span')]
    print(x)
```